# MYSQL denormalized data finding and deleting duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have example data

```
ID DAY ORDER TIME PRODUCT
 1   1    1    1     1 
 2   1    1    1     2
 3   1    1    1     3
 4   1    2    2     1
 5   1    2    2     2
 6   1    2    2     3
 7   1    2    *3*   1
 8   1    2    *3*   2
 9   1    2    *3*   3
```

I want to prevent to having mltiple orders in different time at same day. if I set unique index on DAY,ORDER,TIME I will not be able to insert multiple time anyway, but I want to disable multiple different TIME. Is this possible with mysql?

Have can I find all records where there multiple different TIME value in same DAY and ORDER and delete them?

in this case I would like to delete records 7,8 ad 9 with SQL query because it is duplicate ORDER inserted.

I don't want to normalize table I will stick with this database structure.

Thank you very much

Comment: May be unique index by four fields (day, order, time, product) will help the case? Or there could be multiple product orders within one day,order,time entry?

Comment: yes i can have multiple product orders within one,day,time entry so that will not help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delete` with a `join` clause to find the duplicates and delete them:

```
delete
    from t join
         (select day, "order", min(time) as tokeeptime
          from t
          group by day, "order"
         ) tokeep
         on t.day = tokeep.day and t."order" = tokeep."order" and t.time <> tokeeptime;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE  a
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  a.DAY, a.ORDER, MAX(a.TIME) Time
            FROM    tableName a
            GROUP   BY a.DAY, a.ORDER
            HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT TIME) > 1
        ) b ON a.DAY = b.DAY AND
                a.Order = b.Order AND
                a.Time = b.Time
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7151/1)